# Asp.Net File Writing to folder blocks other visits to the same website until file write finishes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I have an IIS website in ASP.net.
The user can visit the site to export some data from a database as a file which is then downloaded (the file is written to a folder in the asp.net application, and then sent as Response to the user).

The problem:
when the export function takes a long time to read the database and write to a file, it blocks other visits by other people to the website.

Example:

User A exports a very large dataset, and it takes about 30 seconds to write and export the file. During this 30 seconds, if User B visits the same site, the web page will not load finish until the file write finishes for User A.

Is this a common problem? Is there any way to prevent the blocking from happening? Thanks for reading

Comment: That entirely depends on your code.

Comment: please elaborate, i am trying to figure out a way to prevent file writing from blocking the thread

Comment: Just 2 functions, one function to write: it just writes the data from datatable to a file. The other function to output the file as Response. The problem is the dataset is large, and the file is large, and this will block other visits to the site. Do u know if there is a general solution to this kind of file writing issues

Comment: You should probably not always write the same file.